# Typescript Field Type Not Enforced When Assigning

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a constructor that sets the value of **_device**, the field is of type **number** and the constructor parameter is of type **number** as well.

But when a **string** is passed to the constructor, it assigns that string to the field (which is of type number).

I'm not sure what else I can try besides strictly checking the type of the incoming argument to make sure it is number, I would rather have Typescript handle this.

I'm thinking that my issue is how the socketio arguments are coming in.
Is it allowed to declare a type like this?

```
{
joinRoom: { 
          roomId: string, 
          intent: number
        }, 
        playerData: { 
          name: string,
          device: number
        }
}
```

**Player Class**

```js
export class Player {
  private _name: string;
  private _socketId: string;
  private _isReady: boolean;
  private team: string;
  private _device: number;

 /**
  * Creates an instance of Player.
  * @param {string} name
  * @param {string} socketId
  * @param {number} device
  * @memberof Player
  */
  constructor(name: string, socketId: string, device: number) {
    this._name = name;
    this._isReady = false;
    this._socketId = socketId;
    this._device = device;
  }
...
```

**RoomLogic Class**

```js
/**
   * @private
   * @param {*} socket
   * @memberof RoomLogic
   */
  private joinRoom(socket: any) {
    socket.on(CONSTANTS.JOIN_ROOM, 
      (
        joinRoom: { 
          roomId: string, 
          intent: number
        }, 
        playerData: { 
          name: string,
          device: number
        }
      ) => {

      const noRooms = this.utils.isObjectEmpty(this._rooms);
      const roomAlreadyExists = !this.utils.isUndefined(this._rooms[joinRoom.roomId]);
      const isValid = this.isPlayerDataValid(playerData);

      if (isValid.isSuccessful === false) {
        return socket.emit(CONSTANTS.JOIN_ROOM, isValid);
      }

      if (this.utils.isSame(joinRoom.intent, JoinRoomIntents.CreateNewRoom)) {

        // should never be hit, but keep in case
        if (roomAlreadyExists) {
          return socket.emit(CONSTANTS.JOIN_ROOM, {
            isSuccessful: false,
            value: `room with id: ${joinRoom.roomId} already exists`
          });
        }

        let player = new Player(playerData.name, socket.id, playerData.device);
...
```

What I am expecting to happen is Typescript to catch this and throw some kind of error, either on compile or in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not perform runtime checks. The fact that you've told it

```
playerData: { 
  name: string,
  device: number
}
```

allows TypeScript to check that the type `playerData.device` matches the expected type for your constructor's `device` parameter at compile time, which it does. If you do not trust that your incoming data matches the type declaration you've given it, you also need to perform a runtime check as well.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense, since I’m saying that the type of playerData: { device } is ```number```. Then Typescript will take it to be number in my ```Player``` classes constructor as well.